# Is the entry for the "Brixashulty" (RotW) erroneous?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, errata

I can't seem to find any errata on this, but some of the entries of the Brixashulty (RotW p. 186-187) seem wrong to me. Specifically I am thinking of these:

**Saves:**

The Brixashulty has 2 HD, which as an animal type grants it a bonus of +3 on Fortitude and Reflex saves. It has Dex +3, Con +3 and Wis +1 and no other feats or racial modifiers on saves. If I haven't missed anything that would give it Fort +6, Ref +6 and Will +1. However in the entry it says the Brixashulty has Fort +7, Ref +7, Will +2.

**Bull Rush**

A Brixashulty has Str +1 and a +4 racial bonus on bull rush performed after its gore attack (which is specifically what I am talking about). Since no other modifiers are added, shouldn't this rather be a bull rush bonus of +5 instead of the said +7? The only way I can see this goes up to +7 is after a charge, which adds +2 to any bull rush, however the description doesn't say anything about a charge being necessary.

Comment: The harder you look at monster entries, the worse they get. (Also see [this answer.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134584/8610))

Comment: So as a GM would you correct the stats or would you just go along with it? It seems to me it would be much easier to just go along with the entry as is ; and I would not have to disappoint my Gnome players by nerfing their mounts.

Comment: Are you nerfing it if it's wrong? If it were wrong to the gnome's detriment, would you improve it? (I'd suggest opening another question—because that's a really good one—, but I think the topic's more suited to a forum.)

Comment: I guess I am more afraid that I would develop some sort of OCD and check every monster for hours... although this is probably going to happen now anyway. I am not active in any forum, so if you like to discuss that topic, I am afraid you will have to start it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is erroneous.

You are correct on your calculations, but you could come up with 2 kinds of errata:

1. Calculations were done wrong while writing the creature's entry: Reduce the Saves to +6/+6/+1 and the Knockback's bull rush bonus to +5.
2. There is a typo on the Knockback ability description, change the racial bull rush bonus from +4 to +6, also there is a missing entry that the editor forgot to write, add the next paragraph to the creature's combat section:

> ***Racial features***: Brixashulties, like halflings, are
>   surprisingly capable of avoiding mishaps, which grants them a +1
>   racial bonus on all saving throws.